# How can I make my code more optimised using functions?

Tags: python, optimization

**I have a code where python sorts parameters by another ones using zips and lambdas.**
So the question is how can I make it easier an more optimised. **Thanks in ADVANCE!**

```
# Declaring initial lists
zipped1 = zip(al2, al3)

# Converting to list
zipped1 = list(zipped1)


# Using sorted and lambda
res1 = sorted(zipped1, key=lambda x: x[1])

# printing result
help1 = [x for x, y in res1]
fine1 = iter(help1)
```

Comment: Functions don't really __optimize__ the code. Instead, they are used to make code re-usable and properly structured.

Comment: So if not with functions, how can i shrink my code?

Comment: What are you expecting it to look like or to happen when it is "optimised"? What exact problem are you trying to solve? It's not clear..

Comment: I want it to be in one line for example

Comment: Again, why does it have to be in one line? Reducing it to one line does not necessarily make it optimized. Sometimes, it even makes it less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get rid of `zipped1` and `help1` entirely, like so:

```py
fine1 = [x for x, _ in sorted(zip(al2, al3), key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

Although this won't optimize your code speed wise, just size wise.

Comment: There is no need for the intermediate lists, and subsequently the last ``iter``. Just ``fine1 = (x for x, _ in sorted(zip(al2, al3), key=lambda x: x[1]))`` does the same.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Good shout, I've edited that in

Comment: Finally I made like this: fine1 = iter([x for x, y in sorted(list(zip(al2, al3)), key=lambda x: x[1])])

Comment: @elbekrustamov But what does the creation of the list and the call to `iter` do that a generator created with `fine1 = (x for x, _ in sorted(zip(al2, al3), key=lambda x: x[1]))` can't do?